# Create a table for Phalcon model

Tags: php, sql, phalcon

I am a beginner in Phalcon PHP Framework.

I've created a model. Like this:

```
class User extends Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{

    /**
     * @Primary
     * @Identity
     * @Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    public $username;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    public $email;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    public $first_name;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    public $last_name;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    public $password;

    public function getSource()
    {
        return "users";
    }
}
```

So now I want to do some ORM operations.

```
User::count(array('email = :email:', 'email' => $email)) == 0;
```

And I getting this error:
`SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dbname.users' doesn't exist`

The table is really not exists, so how I should create it? Manually via SQL Query or using a specific tool in Phalcon Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a brief review of the phalcon docs i suppose that you are looking for something like this => [Phalcon PHP creating tables](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/db.html#creating-tables)

Sample of usage:

```
<?php
use \Phalcon\Db\Column as Column;

$connection->createTable(
    "robots",
    null,
    array(
       "columns" => array(
            new Column("id",
                array(
                    "type"          => Column::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    "size"          => 10,
                    "notNull"       => true,
                    "autoIncrement" => true,
                )
            ),
            new Column("name",
                array(
                    "type"    => Column::TYPE_VARCHAR,
                    "size"    => 70,
                    "notNull" => true,
                )
            ),
            new Column("year",
                array(
                    "type"    => Column::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    "size"    => 11,
                    "notNull" => true,
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Howto setup a migration : [Source](http://phalcon-php-framework-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/migrations.html)

[image]

> By default Phalcon Developer Tools use the app/migrations directory to
>   dump the migration files. You can change the location by setting one
>   of the parameters on the generation script. Each table in the database
>   has its respective class generated in a separated file under a
>   directory referring its version:

[image]

> Each file contains a unique class that extends the
>   Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Migration These classes normally have two methods:
>   up() and down(). Up() performs the migration, while down() rolls it
>   back.
>
> Up() also contains the magic method morphTable(). The magic comes when
>   it recognizes the changes needed to synchronize the actual table in
>   the database to the description given.

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Db\Column as Column;
use Phalcon\Db\Index as Index;
use Phalcon\Db\Reference as Reference;

class ProductsMigration_100 extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        $this->morphTable(
            "products",
            array(
                "columns" => array(
                    new Column(
                        "id",
                        array(
                            "type"          => Column::TYPE_INTEGER,
                            "size"          => 10,
                            "unsigned"      => true,
                            "notNull"       => true,
                            "autoIncrement" => true,
                            "first"         => true,
                        )
                    ),
                    new Column(
                        "product_types_id",
                        array(
                            "type"     => Column::TYPE_INTEGER,
                            "size"     => 10,
                            "unsigned" => true,
                            "notNull"  => true,
                            "after"    => "id",
                        )
                    ),
                    new Column(
                        "name",
                        array(
                            "type"    => Column::TYPE_VARCHAR,
                            "size"    => 70,
                            "notNull" => true,
                            "after"   => "product_types_id",
                        )
                    ),
                    new Column(
                        "price",
                        array(
                            "type"    => Column::TYPE_DECIMAL,
                            "size"    => 16,
                            "scale"   => 2,
                            "notNull" => true,
                            "after"   => "name",
                        )
                    ),
                ),
                "indexes" => array(
                    new Index(
                        "PRIMARY",
                        array("id")
                    ),
                    new Index(
                        "product_types_id",
                        array("product_types_id")
                    )
                ),
                "references" => array(
                    new Reference(
                        "products_ibfk_1",
                        array(
                            "referencedSchema"  => "invo",
                            "referencedTable"   => "product_types",
                            "columns"           => array("product_types_id"),
                            "referencedColumns" => array("id"),
                        )
                    )
                ),
                "options" => array(
                    "TABLE_TYPE"      => "BASE TABLE",
                    "ENGINE"          => "InnoDB",
                    "TABLE_COLLATION" => "utf8_general_ci",
                )
            )
        );
        // insert some products
        self::$_connection->insert(
            "products",
            array("Malabar spinach", 14.50),
            array("name", "price")
        );
    }
}
```

> Once the generated migrations are uploaded on the target server, you
>   can easily run them as shown in the following example:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Where is better to locate this code to create tables automatically?

Comment: you only need to run this code once, prepare a file that will be called only for initial setup